# Can't port forward a minecraft server with my TP-Link router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding

I am trying to set up a modded MC server for me and my friends, and therefore i need to open my ports on my router.
I have spend hours, and feel like I've tried everything there is to try. I am using a TP-Link AC1200 router.

Things I've done so far:

-Logged in on my router, and port forwarded the MC ports UDP/TCP.

-Made inbound and outbound rules on my windows firewall to allow the port 25565, also UDP/TCP.

-Checked that my WAN IP adress is public.

-Checked that DHCP is enabled.

-Even tried to setup Port Triggering, not sure what it is, but it sure didn't work.

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Is this the port 25565 your Minecraft listen?

Comment: Did you check that your _router's_ WAN IP address (i.e. the one shown in TP-Link's settings interface) is public?

Comment: @user1686 I went to "status" in my browser, and under WAN it says IP Address: X(Dynamic IP). So I went to whatismyip.com and checked my public IP there. The 2 IP addresses match, so I guess that means that my routers WAN IP address is public?